# incrementing counter in multiple text file

Tags: php, counter, increment

I'm trying to increment a counter in a multiple text file when a user visit my page, but the code I'm working is not working below is the code

```
$files = glob("counters/visit/*.txt");


foreach($files as $file) {
    $content = file_get_contents($file);


    if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
      $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
      $content++;
      $f = fopen($files, "w");
      fwrite($f, $content);
      fclose($f);
    }
}
```

Comment: mode "w" is for write as you used but it will overrwrite every time so you should use "a" for appending

Comment: Give you some errors?

Comment: no errors but its not incrementing @valbrux

Comment: I change "w" but still it's not incrementing @BunkerBoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that `$content`is an integer by doing the following :

```
$content = intval(file_get_contents($file));
```

Then you're using :

`$f = fopen($files, "w");`

Instead of :

`$f = fopen($file, "w");`

`fopen` can't accept an array as parameter

Also as mentioned by @alanlittle, if you want all your files to be incremented, you should think about the moment where you set `$_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";` and put it at the end of the loop.

Comment: Also, only the first file will get updated, since you set `$_SESSION['hasVisited']`

Comment: Changed `$files` to `$file` but it's still not incrementing @Nirnae

Comment: Also what's the best way to update all the files since `$_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";` is the criteria to check

Comment: Changed the answer to be sure that you're working with integer that you can increment

Comment: and as I said in my answer you could just put `$_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";` after your `foreach()` so the whole loop will be executed or if you really want to put it in your `foreach()` then you could `count($files)` and use an index to set it on the last turn.

Comment: moved `$_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";` after the for each and it now works, I really appreciate